# Comment traduire « walk on eggshells » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais, nous avons l'expression « *walk on eggshells* », qui veut dire « être diplomatique, prudent, essayer de ne pas offenser quelqu'un ». Quelle en serait une bonne traduction ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

En français, on emploie la même expression, à savoir « marcher sur des œufs », qui a exactement le même sens.

Comment: That's actually "walk on eggs", but thanks.  :-)

Comment: Well when we say walking on eggs we imply walking on their shells ;-)

Comment: By the way, it's much more hazardous to walk on *actual* eggs than on the shells, so it seems french people are more timorous on this one ;-)

Comment: I'm asking myself if _marcher sur des oeufs_ means walk on plain eggs (much more solid than shells bits) while _walking on eggs shells_ means walking on shells bits (already broke eggs)? In this sense, it's much more difficult to walk on eggshells than on plain eggs.

Comment: @Sebf: Try walking on plain eggs without breaking them, we'll see what easier